# Mold Growing on Top of Exterior Door

Tags: exterior, outdoor, mold, door-frame

I am not that knowledgeable with mold. On my exterior front door by the head and the door stop I have mold growing. I checked the drywall and it doesn't seem to have any water damage. I was thinking to wipe away the mold but I thought it might comeback twice as worse so I wanted to check and see what the community had to say.

Comment: What kind of mold?

Answer (score 1):

**Background Information**

There are really only [four things necessary](http://www.fsec.ucf.edu/en/consumer/buildings/basics/moldgrowth.htm) for mold growth:

1. [Mold Spores](http://www.cdc.gov/mold/faqs.htm#mold)
2. Mold Food (Organic Substance)
3. Appropriate Temperatures
4. Considerable Moisture

**Resources**

The best way to control [mold growth](http://www2.epa.gov/mold), is to control moisture. One good resource available to you is the [Brief Guide to Mold, Moisture and Your Home](http://www2.epa.gov/mold/printable-version-brief-guide-mold-moisture-and-your-home) from the [US EPA](http://www3.epa.gov/). The [US CDC](http://www.cdc.gov/) has the following recommendations for [decreasing mold exposure](http://www.cdc.gov/mold/faqs.htm#decrease):

- Never mix bleach with ammonia or other household cleaners. Mixing
  bleach with ammonia or other cleaning products will produce
  dangerous, toxic fumes.
- Open windows and doors to provide fresh air.
- Wear non-porous gloves and protective eye wear.
- If the area to be cleaned is more than 10 square feet, consult the
  U.S. Environmental Protection Agency (EPA) guide titled Mold
  Remediation in Schools and Commercial Buildings. Although focused on
  schools and commercial buildings, this document also applies to other
  building types. You can get it by going to the EPA web site at
  http://www.epa.gov/mold/mold_remediation.html.
- Always follow the manufacturer’s instructions when using bleach or
  any other cleaning product.

**Advice**

As a [Certified Indoor Air Quality Technician](http://www.iaqa.org/), I can tell you that [bleach will in fact make mold worse](https://www.normi.org/articles/bleach-mold.php). Bleach is very effective in removing the discoloration but leaves the microflora that will enable the mold to return in exactly the same spot when conditions are right. The most effective means of destroying molds, are [biocides](http://biocidelabs.com/) and [anti-microbial solutions](http://www.sporicidin.com/products/mold-remediation/).

**Recommendation**

As far as your door is concerned, specifically:

- Check the weather stripping and insure a good seal.
- Check the serviceability of your HVAC system. Air Conditioners are
  also dehumidifiers.
- Keep the doors clean of organic substances - mold can even grow on
  dirt.
- Ask an IAQT to test the mold spores and determine the type of mold.
- Clean the area with rubbing [alcohol](http://www.cps.ca/documents/position/antimicrobial-products-in-the-home), or a solution with 60%-90%
  alcohol.

Comment: No biocides or anti-microbial solutions are EPA registered for use as a fungicide on wood substrates.

Answer (score 0):

Clorox and a hand pump tree soaker/sprayer. Then pressure wash. You will never 'win' with mother nature, but you can sack her behind the line of scrimmage and force a punt.